# How to plot a Pandas df with index timestamp being over midnight, but same date

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have some recorded data from sensor done over night. I want to plot the result as a graph with pyplot. The source file is a csv of timestamp, value. For parsing date I use:
`pd.read_csv(..., date_parser=pd.datetime.strtime(x, 'H%:%M:%S:%f'),...)`

The timestamp of the data is from 23:30:00:000 to 02:30:00:000(only time). When plot'ing my dataframe pyplot assume that the data I want to plot after 23:59:59 is supposed to by plotted earlier that same day. It is because the day(date) is the same for all timestamps, even tough the day changed. 


    `...
    1900-01-01 23:20:27.832   95.0
    1900-01-01 23:20:28.165   95.0
    ...                        ...
    1900-01-01 02:01:14.247   95.0
    1900-01-01 02:01:14.580   95.0
    ...`

The questions is therefore, can I and how can I ignore date and just plot the hours/time sequentially.
Or, how do I read in data from cvs that add one day to the timestamp when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add the date (or relative date) to timestamps appearing after midnight, and then matplotlib will be able to order the timestamps properly.

Since, your daily data beings recording at `23:30` and stops before the next day's `23:30`, you can use this to update the date

*assuming the time column is named `tstamp`*

```
ts = pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01 23:30:00')
df.loc[df.tstamp < ts, 'tstamp'] = df.tstamp[df.tstamp < ts] + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
```

However, note that this method would fail if you recorded more than 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your pdf is named df, I would just recurse through the dates to make sure everyone of them is above the previous one :

```
datestoprocess=df["date"].values
for i in range(1,len(datestoprocess)):
    datestoprocess[i]-= (datestoprocess[i-1]-datestoprocess[i]).days
df["date"]=datestoprocess
```

This sets each date to be right after the previous one, in case it was set before by the parsing.